# How to pull multiple URLs in a single Python Call

Tags: python

I am trying to pull multiple websites in the same Python call. I cannot get it to work correctly and have had to put in each call individually.

I have already tried doing the following:

```
URL = ['https://sc2replaystats.com/replay/playerStats/10758933/83445': https://sc2replaystats.com/replay/playerStats/10758969/83445]
content = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

contentTable  = soup.find('table', "table table-striped table-condensed")
rows = contentTable.find_all('span', "blizzard_icons_single") 
print (rows)
```

Here is my current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # BeautifulSoup is in bs4 package 
import requests

URL = 'https://sc2replaystats.com/replay/playerStats/10758969/83445'
content = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

contentTable  = soup.find('table', "table table-striped table-condensed")
rows = contentTable.find_all('span', "blizzard_icons_single") 
print (rows)
```

Comment: Why do you want to pull mutliple in one call?

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine multiple http requests into one. You can however do them one after the other. Maybe check the python documentation on [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and [loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

```
urls = ['http://example.com', 'http://example.org']
for url in urls:
    content = requests.get(url)
    print(content)
```